# Stationary walk with moving terrain

Tags: animation

How do I create a stationary walk with moving cropped terrain like in the GIF? I can create the walk, but the cropped environment, I can not figure it out.

[image: Stationary walk with moving terrain]

Comment: Use a tileable image texture and move it with the location values of the Mapping node? As for the mushrooms just make them visible the invisible?

Comment: i would recommend using alpha in shader instead of boolean modifier (because boolean is a) often very slow and b) creates bad topology). You could e.g. move the image texture as moonboots proposed and then plugin a mathematical formula like distance to texture position equal 1 to get the round effect

Answer (score 2):

You can use a boolean modifier on the environment (terrain and assets). If the boolean object (a cylinder) is stationary, and the environment moves, you can achieve this effect. You can even assign a separate material (for the sub-terrain layers) to the boolean object and transfer it to the resulting terrain geometry through the boolean modifier.

Comment: I think I will go with MR-A suggestion. It is simple and will work for what I need.
I made the below test his way and works fine. Thank you all. https://i.stack.imgur.com/e787o.gif

Answer (score 1):

Create your character walking on its base, make the floor transparent with the *Holdout* shader, then in the *Compositor* you'll mix these images with the images of the road moving:

[image]

As for the mushrooms, enable their visibility in the *Outliner*.